# Is there any Windows Phone 8 app that supports multi-disc albums?

Tags: music

Xbox Music, Nokia Music, and every third-party music player I could find in the Windows Phone Store all have the same problem: none of them recognize albums having multiple discs. So, if you want to play through an album, you're given a list of track 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3... And to fix it, you'd have to manually compile a playlist. This seems totally absurd to me.

And yet, while multiple people on different forums around the web have mentioned this, NONE of them have mentioned any app that brings a solution. Is that really possible?

I'm running a Nokia Lumia 521, on the latest (Black) update.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that multi-disc albums when matched against the store in X-Box Music on Windows 8, it sequentially numbers the tracks on the later discs after the first,  so it'll go 1,2,3...18,19  for disc 1, and then pick from 20,21...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has this feature listed as `Under Review` on their [Xbox Music UserVoice site](http://xboxmusic.uservoice.com/forums/209733-xbox-music-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5789401-songs-in-multi-disc-albums-cannot-be-sorted-correc). You should certainly go and vote for this.